# How do I derive the Maclaurin series for $\tanh(x)$?

Tags: taylor-expansion, hyperbolic-functions

I've thought of doing it by writing $\tanh(x)$ as $(1-e^{-2x})/(1+e^{-2x})$ and then using the Maclaurin series for $e^{x}$ or just as $\sinh(x)/\cosh(x)$ and using the Maclaurin series for $\sinh(x)$ and $\cosh(x)$ but I don't get the same results. I can do it by evaluating the derivatives but I'm not sure if that's the most efficient way, which is what I need.
$$
\tanh(x)=\frac {\sinh(x)} {\cosh(x)}=\frac {1-e^{-2x}} {1+e^{-2x}}
$$
I get:
$$
\tanh(x)=\frac {\sinh(x)} {\cosh(x)}=\frac {x+\frac {x^3} {3!}+\frac {x^5} {5!}+\dots} {1+\frac {x^2} {2!}+\frac {x^4} {4!}+\dots}
$$
and
$$
\tanh(x)=\frac{1-e^{-2x}} {1+e^{-2x}}=\frac{1-(1-2x+\frac{4x^2}{2!}+\dots)} {1+(1-2x+\frac{4x^2}{2!}+\dots)}=\dots
$$
which don't look the same to me.

Comment: Neither is a Maclaurin series, which has to look like $\sum a_n x^n$. You can do a formal division, and obtain after some pain a few terms. Alternately, you can expand $\frac{1}{1+e^{-2x}}$ using the usual series for $\frac{1}{1+t}$ and substituting. It will be painful to go any distance. Or you can take derivatives and obtain a few terms. The Maclaurin series is quite messy. One can obtain an expression for the $a_n$ in terms of Bernoulli numbers, not easy.

Comment: In general, I believe it is a *difficult* problem to divide two infinite series to get another infinite series. And comparing two ratios of infinite series is also not trivial, unless you're talking about the trivial case, for example when one can be reduced to the other by just cancelling a constant multiplier. Your best bet is to find the Taylor series using the series of derivatives of $\tanh x$.

Comment: Another option is start with the Taylor series for the inverse function, $\text{artanh}$, which is rather easier to derive, and use the Lagrange Inversion Formula to produce the coefficients of the series for $\tanh$. In principle one can set up an inductive proof to show that this formula produces the coefficients of the Taylor series for $\tanh$ in terms of (like Andre points out) the Bernoulli numbers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#The_Lagrange_inversion_formula

Comment: The second and third expressions are the same after the long division.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep in mind that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\tanh x=1-\tanh^2 x$$
and
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(i)}(a)}{i!}(x-a)^i$$
is the Taylor series where we CAN have in some series $a=0$.
With some work you get
$$\tanh x=\sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2i}4^i(4^i-1)}{(2i)!}x^{2i-1}$$
where $B_j$ is the $j$th [Bernoulli number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number).